# Change the background color and icons on the button when pressed

Tags: flutter, button

I have buttons with icons that act as indicators. They have a background color and an icon color. I want these buttons to change their background color and icon color when clicked and stay that way until the next click.

[image: That block]

This is how I implement it:

```
Widget _deviceManagement() {return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 20),
    child: Container(
      height: 86,
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        color: secondary,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          _doubleTear(),
          const Spacer(),
          _lightbulb(),
          const Spacer(),
          _megaphone(),
          const Spacer(),
          _water(),
          const Spacer(),
          _expandButton(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here's what one block element looks like:

```
Widget _doubleTear() {return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
    child: Container(
      width: 54,
      height: 54,
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        color: tertiary,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
        },
        elevation: 0,
        color: tertiary,
        splashColor: Main,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/li-double-tear.svg', color: textSecondary)
      )
    ),
  );
}
```

I have tried all kinds of buttons, such as the Elevated Button, etc., but I only manage to change the color at the moment of pressing, but when I release the button, the color becomes the same again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use [ToggleButtons](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html) with or without multi-select and style it how you want it.

If you want to use `ElevatedButton` then you need to introduce a boolean field which stores the state of the button (if it is activated or not) and switch between the stylings based on that boolean value.